# jQuery mouseenter effect not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to apply the `colored filter` (which is in my css) effect when I `mouseenter` with jQuery. The `mouseenter` must be applied to the sidebar (which has the `class="sidebar"`).

For some reason I can not make the mouseenter work when on a sidebar. 
In this case the feathers, the text and the sidebar need to become colored.

Pleas help.

See this fiddle for more information: http://fiddle.jshell.net/897mC/2/

Comment: Strange. When I click on the fiddle link it opens up. 
Can you please try this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/22Vhs/

And what are the errors in my fiddle exactly? 
Because you said I have many errors in my fiddle.

Comment: I just added the jquery library to the html.
Does it work now? 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/897mC/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a [working sample here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gB6Sx/5/) that achieves the desired effect for the feathers and top bar.

You can't control whether or not a CSS class applies to an element by using setting `display` to `none`.

When you have `display: none` in a CSS class, you're saying that any HTML element that has that class is not going to show up.

You should instead add and remove the desired classes from your target elements as needed:

```
$("#home_top").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#topBar").removeClass("sGray");
    $("#topBar").addClass("sColor");
    $("#featherOne, #featherTwo").removeClass("fGray");
    $("#featherOne, #featherTwo").addClass("fColor");
});

$("#home_top").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#topBar").removeClass("sColor");
    $("#topBar").addClass("sGray");
    $("#featherOne, #featherTwo").removeClass("fColor");
    $("#featherOne, #featherTwo").addClass("fGray");
});
```

To achieve the delay that you're looking for, your CSS class should contain the transition for the desired property:

```
-webkit-transition: filter 750ms ease-in;
       -moz-transition: filter 750ms ease-in;
        -ms-transition: filter 750ms ease-in;
         -o-transition: filter 750ms ease-in;
            transition: filter 750ms ease-in;
```

Comment: No this is not it. 
I want to make the colored version active when mouseenter. 
This is just appearing the gray version again. 

I need it to load with the gray version and after the mouseenter make it colored. 

The colored filter is inside the css.

Comment: Ah! I understand your problem now. Let me see if I can help.

Comment: I edited the fiddle link in my question. Thx for letting me know. 

Also I already have display:none; inside my css for the coloured filter class. I am trying to call that class with jQuery. And that is not working for me.

Comment: I have a grayscaled version AND a coloured version. 
The grayscaled version is visible as you can see. But the coloured version has display:none; 

They are in the same <div> and this is probably interfering. 
If I take out the display:none, the coloured version works fine. 

but I only want it to work AFTER mouseenter. on the class="sidebar"

Thanks.

Comment: Does what you need to do make sense now?

Comment: I understood your answer partially. Added your code and it is not what I want. But yes, we are getting closer. 

You gave the background color a color of your own. I am trying to make the colored version of the background , feathers an text visible with a delay once mouseentered. 

please see this link: http://demo.chilipress.com/Test

I also need to have event delegation in the function. It's much better coded that way.

Comment: Also take a look here: http://demo.chilipress.com/epicforever
See the effect when you mouseenter one of the sidebars. It get's colored and so does the text. (don't mind the feathers there). 
This is exactly the effect I am trying to achieve on this page: http://demo.chilipress.com/Test

Comment: Yes, I believe if we keep messaging we can. What I've provided for you is a way to get what you want: add and remove the desired CSS classes as needed (on mouseenter and mouseleave).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51216/discussion-between-skeryl-and-brain)

Comment: @Brain, can you please visit the working sample. I believe I have achieved the desired effect.